# Init.d script not working on startup: Failed to start SYSV

Tags: debian, services, init-script, init.d, chkconfig

The Keystone CMS system fails to run on startup. The problem is likely in this `init.d` startup script. I set the permissions, but something is still not right.

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo service keystone start
Job for keystone.service failed. See 'systemctl status keystone.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
$ sudo service keystone status
● keystone.service - SYSV: Keystone server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/keystone)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-10-13 07:39:12 UTC; 16s ago
  Process: 2785 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/keystone start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 2698 (code=exited, status=216/GROUP)

Oct 13 07:39:12 test-vm systemd[2785]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/keystone: Exec format error
Oct 13 07:39:12 test-vm systemd[1]: keystone.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Oct 13 07:39:12 test-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Keystone server daemon.
Oct 13 07:39:12 test-vm systemd[1]: Unit keystone.service entered failed state.
```

It could be the script itself, which was created [from a template](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html). I was also thinking about linking it to one of `/etc/rc?.d` directories.

I'm using Debian 8.6

`/etc/init.d/keystone`:

```
Subsystem file for "Keystone" server
#
# chkconfig: 2345 95 05
# description: Keystone server daemon

RETVAL=0
prog="keystone"

start() {       
        echo -n $"Starting $prog:"

        cd /home/user/keystone
        /opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node  /home/user/keystone/keystone.js

        RETVAL=$?
        [ "$RETVAL" = 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/$prog
        echo
}

stop() {        
        echo -n $"Stopping $prog:"

        killproc $prog -TERM
        RETVAL=$?
        [ "$RETVAL" = 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$prog
        echo
}

reload() {
        echo -n $"Reloading $prog:"
        killproc $prog -HUP
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
}

case "$1" in
        start)
                start
                ;;
        stop)
                stop
                ;;
        restart)
                stop
                start
                ;;
        reload)
                reload
                ;;
        condrestart)
                if [ -f /var/lock/subsys/$prog ] ; then
                        stop
                        # avoid race
                        sleep 3
                        start
                fi
                ;;
        status)
                status $prog
                RETVAL=$?
                ;;
        *)
                echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|condrestart|status}"
                RETVAL=1
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Process: 2785 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/keystone start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
…
Oct 13 07:39:12 test-vm systemd[2785]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/keystone: Exec format error
```

… which is entirely correct.  Your file is not an executable script.  It lacks an interpreter.  It's also not in the correct form that is prescribed for old van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts by Debian Policy, hence the "`SYSV:`" (rather than "`LSB:`") that systemd has prefixed to its description.

But it's also a waste of time to fix it.  Throw it away.  Write a systemd service unit.

```
[Unit]
Description=Keystone CMS
Documentation=http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316168/5132

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/keystone
ExecStart=/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node /home/user/keystone/keystone.js

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Further reading

- https://askubuntu.com/a/835318/43344