# Reducing shutdown timeout for "a stop job is running"

Tags: systemd, reboot, lsb

I've got node.js and pm2 installed on a Pi (Raspbian). PM2 was configured to start via `pm2 startup` and the init scripts it creates. Sometimes when I reboot, shutdown hangs for a few minutes on:

```
A stop job is running for LSB: PM2 init script (... / 5min)
```

Every once in a while<sup>1</sup> what I'm assuming is PM2 doesn't shut down properly and hangs for the full 5 minutes.

On this system, I know exactly what apps PM2 is managing and I really don't care if they shutdown properly.

My question is: How do I reduce the timeout from 5 minutes to, say, 15 seconds or so? Where is this configured?

I read on a forum that it was the `DefaultTimeoutStopSec` key in */etc/systemd/system.conf*, so I tried setting that to "15s" but it had no effect. I tried the same thing in */etc/systemd/user.conf*, too, but no change. The timeout is still set to 5 minutes.

---

<sup>1</sup> I actually do know specifically what triggers this, but the details aren't important and the effect is unavoidable.

Comment: If there is a (default) `stop` script, you could re-write it to perform a `forcestop` or even to kill `pm2` instead of a graceful shutdown.

Comment: @Tigger I came to a similar conclusion, actually. Out of desperation I just made `stop` in pm2's init script do nothing at all, and let it die naturally on shutdown. It's a terrible solution for general use but on this particular system it's fine. I still want to know how to change the 5 minute timeout though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How do I reduce the timeout from 5 minutes to, say, 15 seconds or so?

You re-build systemd from source, patching [the hardwired timeout in `systemv-sysv-generator`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v232/src/sysv-generator/sysv-generator.c#L193) from `TimeoutSec=5min` to whatever you want.  Or you ask the systemd people for a control knob somewhere in the Fedora/SUSE or LSB headers.

Or, on the gripping hand, you give up on using this `rc` script that you have and write a systemd service unit for your service, whose timeouts you can set with an explicit `TimeoutSec=` setting, installed with a drop-in settings file in `/etc/systemd/system/pm2.service.d/timeout.conf` if necessary.

Given [this](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2354), [this](https://c.dataglen.com/platform/uddhav-internship/blob/master/day3/node_modules/pm2/lib/scripts/pm2.service), [this](https://docs.omniref.com/js/npm/pm2/0.12.7/files/lib/scripts/pm2.service), [this](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/308), [this](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#startup-systems-support), and others, the first rule for migrating to systemd applies here as well.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316369/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326354/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316168/5132
- https://askubuntu.com/a/626858/43344
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*The systemd House of Horror*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/).  Frequently Given Answers.

Answer (score 27):

`/etc/systemd/system.conf` has a line

`#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s`

which can be uncommented and changed

Comment: I mentioned that in my post and that changing it has no effect.

Comment: setting 45s in Arch Linux makes shutdowns quick on an `nvme` drive - for really quick shutdowns use Alpine Linux (no `systemd`)